How to Resize an Animated GIF in a Chrome extension using JavaScript?
There is a website that I use that uses XenForo. They don't allow GIF avatars but you can upload it and it saves it as original (maybe downsized to a point). XenForo servers images as o, l, m, s; respectively original, large, medium, small. It resizes it on the server and if it's a GIF, it makes it as JPEG for the s, m, l versions. They always use .jpg as file extension so detecting if an image is GIF or not is also an issue.
I want to make a Chrome extension to resize and save the images locally. The image URL's have timestamps, so I can detect if it's changed or not. The issue is resizing animated GIFs in JS. All I could find is Node.JS. Sharp is pretty good about this. I wrote this but couldn't find anything that allows me to do it on the extension itself.
The userbase of the website isn't that big. Also not everyone uses GIFs. It would take lots of space but shouldn't kill a computer.
This is the Sharp code. With the GIFs I've tried, WebP produces smaller output. I can use sharpInstance.metadata() to detect the image format.
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import sharp from "sharp";
function f(imageURL, size) {
    return fetch(imageURL)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => sharp(buffer, { animated: true }))
        .then(sharpInstance => sharpInstance
            .resize(size, size)
            .webp()
            .toBuffer()
            .then(data => `data:image/webp;base64,${ data.toString('base64') }`));
}

I’m looking for suggestions on how to resize animated GIFs directly in a browser environment, specifically within a Chrome extension. The solution needs to be efficient and handle the conversion to WebP if possible. Any advice or library recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I tried using canvas but couldn't figure it out with GIFs. The rest used Node.js and as far as I know you can't use it in Chrome extensions.

You should attempt to go back to basics using one of the following two methods (before using a library, at least):

Create an HTMLImage object and use the width/height properties:
const myimg = new Image();
myimage.height = int; myimg.width = int;

Apply the base64 encoded string data to an element you can reference with a CSS selector (ex. id or classname). Then, use CSS with the JavaScript object's style property:
const img = document.querySelector('id');
img.style.width = '200px'; img.src = theDataInYourCode;


While the above is simple pseudocode, I hope it helps trigger the actual solution from a different perspective. I'm unfamiliar with the library you're using, however.

Here's a link to something that may be helpful as well:
How to display Base64 images in HTML

All of the posted answers show different ways of creating images with the data you're getting. The point to take away is that once you've got a reference to the DOM object, you should be able to easily manipulate the dimensions using it's properties or CSS (style property) attributes. Without creating an actual DOM object (doesn't need to be inserted into the document but must be an Image object), you'd have to rely on a server-based process.


I don't think we understand each other. I don't want to be rude but like every single word of your answer is wrong for the topic. The page already has img elements. I'm not trying to make it pretty, I'm trying to make it efficient. With your way I can just replace sml URLs with o URLs. But I shouldn't try to load 20-100 GIFs up to 3.5 MB to load a page. A 3.5 MB GIF can be 22, 60, 192 KB for 48, 96, 192 px sizes when it's downscaled and saved as WebP. I can ignore the large size and use original link for that because it's really rare but other than that, the only logical way seems to be WebP.

You're talking about creating new files with a browser. You can't do that within the framework you've laid out. .You need to use a server-based process. Don't forget, there's very real reasons why you can't do what you're suggesting due to security concerns on the client-side. Imagine the havoc an extension developer could reap if they could just create files on the user's machine at-will. I would, instead, suggest rethinking your approach to the "problem" you're attempting to solve.

A GIF is made of bytes and JavaScript has UInt8Array. So, you can. I think I explained it clearly. There are some GIF images. I want to resize and use them as data URL's. You can make a data URL from a GIF. I just need the resizing part. I'm not gonna create files. I'm gonna create data URLs. I already can do that and use it. The problem is data URL is too long, takes up storage and load time. You don't need 1080x1080 image to show it in a 48x48 area. My approach is good. I don't care this to read all GIF89a specs and implement it by myself. I know it is possible.

If you eventually find your answer or some solution that solves your issue, please don't forget to inform others and myself here. Sometimes people find solutions elsewhere or come up with it on their own .... without remembering to update their original post. While it appears to be a very unique case in terms of browser extension development, I'm sure somebody at some point in the future would benefit from any solution you feel it would be appropriate to share. Also, I'm definitely curious what you use to solve your issue -- if, eventually, you do. Regardless, thanks for the post and comments.
